# how to access a struts2 property value in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

```
<s:iterator value="MyList" status="idx">
     <% int index = %><s:property value = '%{#idx.index}'/><% ; %>
</s:iterator>
```

The above code does not work.
how can the integer value of the 'idx' be stored in the variable 'index'?

Comment: Scriplets are bad. What do you want to do? Why to *store* `idx.index` in `index`?

Comment: My others variables are inside scriplets. i would like to check this index variable with the other java variables inside the scriplets. say <% if(index == pageno) {%> <s:property value="userName" /> <% } %>

Comment: Why are you trying to do it like this? I can't think of any reasonable justification. The value is on the value stack, but rather than start adding ugly on top of ugly, why not just fix it and do it right?

Comment: yes, if i am to do it as you say it is possible. now that i know it is ugly, i still want to know if there is any possible way to store in java variable in the scriplet?

Comment: You should not. Stop doing code like ten years ago, and start using taglibs. Your refactoring from scriptlet to full Struts2 tags (or JSTL in non-struts2 projects) will be fast, easy and meaningful. Your skills will grow and you'll become a better developer. Know how to do the abomination requested will simply let you "fix" (!) the code in 5 minutes, and will let you in the swamp of worst-practices you are now, so NOT providing it to you is the best thing. You could instead post a sample of your code asking how to refactoring it in the *right* way, and we will happily help you on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using java variables creating a struts variable works fine.

`<s:set name="newVariable" value="%{#idx.index}" />`

whenever you need to access the newly created struts variable. You can use this

`<s:property value="#newVariable" />`

Comment: yeah you are correct. I have changed it, this is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

you can access the list value in jsp using

```
<s:property value="dataname"/>
```

dataname is your pojo generated database columns